# Remote Computer Access

Tags: remote-access

I have used Logmein in the past for remote access for Windows.  What application is recommended for remote access for ubuntu 14.04? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Vino/VNC is a common choice.  Full instructions for setup are in the community wiki [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers).  You can connect with [Remmina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remmina).